# java.util.Scanner's useDelimiter(" ") or useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\s")) work different than standard behaviour

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Given the code below, it outputs:

```
Feed a chunk of data here:           
I have found:   0 words; 0 ints; 0 booleans;
```

if I type 10 spaces and leave the two useDelimiter method invokations commented, and outputs:

```
Feed a chunk of data here:           
I have found:   9 words; 0 ints; 0 booleans;
sssssssss
```

if I type the very same 10 spaces but do use one of the two useDelimiter invocations.
Why is it like this? Shouldn't be the same? Here is the code, thank you:

```
package com.riccardofinazzi.regex;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ScanNext {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* match counters */
        int hits_s = 0, hits_i = 0, hits_b = 0;

        /* current token value */
        String  s;
        Integer i;
        Boolean b;

        ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();

        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.console().readLine("Feed a chunk of data here: "));

        /* not needed as this is def behaviour, I put it here to not forget the method */

        //s1.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\s"));
        //s1.useDelimiter(" ");

        while(s1.hasNext()) {
            if (        s1.hasNextInt()) {
                        al.add(s1.nextInt());       hits_i++;

            } else if ( s1.hasNextBoolean()) {
                        al.add(s1.nextBoolean());   hits_b++;

            } else {    al.add(s1.next());          hits_s++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("I have found:\t"+hits_s+" words; "+hits_i+" ints; "+hits_b+" booleans;");

        for (Object in : al) {
            if (in instanceof String)
                System.out.print("s");
            if (in instanceof Integer)
                System.out.print("i");
            if (in instanceof Boolean)
                System.out.print("b");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets say that `X` is delimiter.

If we scan text like `"aXbXc"` it is clear that there are 3 tokens: `"a"` `"b"` and `"c"`.

If we scan text like `"aXXc"` there are still 3 tokens, but this time: `"a"` `""` and `"c"`. That is because we set delimiter to match only one `X` at a time so it doesn't see another `X` as continuation of already matched delimiter but as separate one.
(This is very useful in cases like when delimiter is `,` and we scan data like `1,2,,,3` because it *should* represent elements: `1` `2` `noData` `noData` `3`).
If you would like delimiter to represent one or more `X` you would need to use `X+` since `+` is quantifier representing "once or more". This way `aXXc` would represent only `"a"` and `"c"` elements since whole `XX` would be seen as one delimiter.

Other interesting case is `aXbX`. As you see there is no `c` here, ***text ends with delimiter***. In such case Scanner doesn't assume that there is empty element after last delimiter so it sees only `"a"` and `"b"` as tokens, not `"a", "b", ""`.

Same applies for `XbXc` where ***text starts with delimiter***. Scanner doesn't assume that there is some empty element before it.

---

Now lets go back to your case.

If you print Scanner's default delimiter (using code like `System.out.println(s1.delimiter());`) you will see that it is `\p{javaWhitespace}+`. So by default delimiter is **one or more whitespaces**. But later you change it to *single* space or family of whitespaces. This means that for string

```
"          "
```

- if delimiter is `\p{javaWhitespace}+` then the whole expression is matched as *one* delimiter so there are no elements before, after, and between delimiter, so there are 0 tokens (non-delimiter elements)
- but if we use `" "` or `"\\s"` as delimiter then Scanner will find 10 delimiters (each space is *one* of them). Since there are 10 delimiters, this means that there are 9 elements *between* them (even empty strings count). Also text starts and ends with delimiter, which means there are no tokens before first delimiter, or after last one.

Comment: It doesn't seem to behave the way you describe. With `useDelimiter(" ")`, and an input starting with and ending with multiple spaces, it will return empty strings at both the start and the end.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I am not sure what you mean. If we try to scan `"___a___"` and set delimiter `_` (I replaced spaces with `_`, otherwise comment would show them as single space) like in https://ideone.com/xOSdYg you will see that we are getting tokens `""` `""` `"a"` `""` `""`. Empty strings come from places marked with `|`: so they come from between delimiters `_|_|_a_|_|_` without empty strings `|___a___|` which are before starting or after trailing delimiter.

Comment: Your reply to my comment seems to be a direct contradiction to what you wrote in your answer: `Other interesting case is aXbX. As you see there is no c here, text ends with delimiter. In such case Scanner doesn't assume that there is empty element after last delimiter so it sees only "a" and  "b" as tokens, not "a", "b", ""`. In fact, in agreement with your reply to my comment, it sees the tokens "a", "b", "". Not just "a" and "b".

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I still don't see contradiction. I didn't say that there are no empty strings before or after delimiters, I said that scanner doesn't see them (in sense as valid tokens - maybe that needs clarification). Here is example confirming that: https://ideone.com/FhMNn1

Comment: I see, you're right, but there seems to be some unintuitive behaviour here:  Scanner doesn't remove all empty tokens at the start and end – if you have N empty tokens at the start or end, Scanner sees N-1 empty tokens. https://ideone.com/qxChPs. Also, the behaviour differs from `String.split()`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou It is easier to understand Scanner when we understand that delimiter is different than separator and terminator (these are not synonyms). In short if we have text like `,a,,` then if `,` is delimiter then we have 2 elements `"a"` and `""`. If `,` is separator we have 3 elements `""` `"a"` and `""`. If `,` is terminator we have 4 elements: `""`, `"a"` `""` `""`. In Scanner we are using delimiters. And yes, Scanner is different than `split()` since it doesn't remove all trailing empty strings, but only one which is after last delimiter.

Comment: That's a good explanation - Scanner uses a delimiter, whereas `String.split` uses a separator (e.g. `",a,,".split(",", -1).length == 4` whereas with Scanner it's 2.) So the important thing is to understand the subtle difference between delimiter and separator. But then Oracle calls Sting.split's argument a delimiter in its documentation, not a separator.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Yes, which is why I can't say that documentation is perfect. Most often after reading it I still need to write some simple tests to check cases which ware not explained fully.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes we need to write code to check the behaviour of badly explained methods; but that worries me since if a behaviour is not documented, there is a small possibility it can change in a new release.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Update: I mixed terminator with separator in my previous comment. So for `,a,,` if `,` is terminator we would get 3 elements, and in case of separator 4 elements.

Answer (score 3):

I read some of the [Scanner documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), which says among other things:

> Depending upon the type of delimiting pattern, empty tokens may be returned. For example, the pattern "\s+" will return no empty tokens since it matches multiple instances of the delimiter. The delimiting pattern "\s" could return empty tokens since it only passes one space at a time.

The reason for the observed behavior is the default delimiter, which is `\\p{javaWhitespace}+` as you can see in `Scanner.WHITESPACE_PATTERN` ([code from OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/8cc500af2454/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#l423)) and `Scanner.reset()` (which resets the delimiter to that pattern). Because of the `+`, it matches your whole input as one delimiter.

If you change your custom delimiters by adding a `+` at the end, they will also treat consecutive whitespace as one delimiter.

Comment: +1, but could you please edit the link to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) back in? This serves both as a source for your quote and helps people to read more.

Comment: In particular, can you please link to the documentation for `Scanner.WHITESPACE_PATTERN`.

Comment: @Justastudent sorry, I think you did that edit just before I clicked submit on my own edit, hence I overwrote your change. I have added the links again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. No worries! I commented in case you were still editing, probably should have done that in the first place. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the two whitespace patterns that you attempted match the default delimiter, which is `"\\p{javaWhitespace}+"`. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) doesn't make this clear: it simply says "A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace." Colloquially "whitespace" implies any number of consecutive whitespace characters.

The definitive specification of the default delimiter is only stated in the documentation of [Scanner.reset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset--), which resets the delimiter to the default.